# SQL Server Temp Dir?

Tags: sql-server, temp

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'set'
```

I need to get the OS temporary directory without resorting to using xp_cmdshell. I am using MSSQL 2008. What's the best way I can do that?

Well, it looks like there is no way to do that from TSQL. I believe SQL Server knows about %temp% because it must use it, but oh well.

Well can anyone recommend a way to make this code more compact/tighter?

```
Set NoCount On
Declare @t VarChar(256)
Declare @env Table ( [Parts] VarChar(256) )
Insert Into @env 
Exec Master..Xp_CmdShell 'set' 
Set @t = (  Select Top 1 [Parts] From @env Where [Parts] Like 'temp=%'  )
Select Replace(@t , 'temp=','' )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use xp_cmdshell or some CLR (not sure of permissions) to read the environment variables `%TEMP%` or `%TMP%`. This gives you the service account folder though. The "common" one is `%WINIR%\Temp`

This isn't something that you'd normally do about in day to day SQL

Comment: Not a normal case. There is some file-writing that is going on and instead of assuming things about drives, I'd like to use the system temp directory since I can "know" the path will have a little bit of space for dump-files. I am sure MSSQL uses the OS temp dir when it needs to, I'd just like to use it too.

Comment: (back from vacation) Based on that, it sounds like you could get away with storing your database-specific files in the same place as the tempdb data files. The main "it depends" factor here is, does anything else besides your SQL process need to have access to those files?

Answer (score 1):

The location of the file used by the tempdb database can be quickly found by running

```
execute tempdb.dbo.sp_helpfile
```

(edit)

...that's not what you're looking for, is it? Barring diving into the sp_OA procedures, I don't think there is any simple way to access OS information of this nature.

Comment: That is amazing that it can't be retrieved. Hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

Try running SSMS as Administrator.

Check this link out....

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/07/23/ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-linked-server-null-returned-message-unspecified-error.aspx

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Scripting.FileSystem` OLE object to get the windows temp folder.

```
declare 
    @tempFolder varchar(260),
    @oleResult int,
    @fs int,
    @folder int;    

    exec @OLEResult = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @fs output;
    exec @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @fs, 'GetSpecialFolder', @folder output, 2        
    exec sp_OAGetProperty @folder , 'Path', @tempfolder OUT
    exec @oleResult = sp_OADestroy @folder
    exec @oleResult = sp_OADestroy @FS

    select @tempFolder
```